# How do I automatically set a custom path for R packages when using MS Visual Studio?

Tags: r, visual-studio

I just got started with MS Visual Studio and am liking it. However, for work reasons I keep all my packages in a custom folder, which is not the default folder for packages. I have modified my `.Rprofile` file to set `.libPaths()` to this path so when I start R by itself it uses that path.  How do I do that for MS Visual Studio?

Please note, I am asking how I get R to automatically know where my packages are when it's started in Visual Studio, not how to issue `.libPaths()` whenever I start R in VS. If it matters, I'm using VS 1.78 (from 2023).